# No Test Runs Listed Under 'Test Runs'

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

In Visual Studio 2012 (Update 2) I have a test. The test is correctly displayed under the Test Explorer window and from there I can run the test and it passes successfully. However I want to view the Test Report in the Test Report window. The problem is that in order to see a Test Report I need to select the test under the Test Runs window and none of my tests are showing up there.

I opened the Test Runs window, and next to 'Connect:' I select 'Connect to test runs...', pick 'Select results from local runs', and choose the default directory of `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\<PROJECT NAME>\TestResults`, after I click OK the Test Runs list changes to just show a tree node for "Completed Runs" but it says there are 0 entries and when I expand the node it is empty.

I went to the `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\<PROJECT NAME>\TestResults` folder in Windows Explorer and I can see that there are several folders in there, presumably containing test run results but I can't be sure.

Why aren't my test runs showing up under 'Completed Runs'? Am I mising a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Test Results window is dropped in VS2012

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/750184/test-results-window-does-not-show-test-results